# Stop NppExec from trapping console output until program finishes

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I'm using Notepad++'s NppExec plugin to execute Python scripts from within Notepad++. I notice that Python console output produced with the `print()` statement doesn't appear on the Notepad++ console until the entire script is finished executing. Is there a way to make print statements appear in real-time?

I'm using Notepad++ v.5.9.8 and NppExec v0.4.1.

Comment: Try `python -u` to run in an unbuffered mode.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: @user8368 - Thanks, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The console window of NppExec is started as a child process, meaning that updating the display of the console window, as well as running the main program, are carried out on a *single thread*. By default, Python print statement outputs are buffered and run on the same thread as the parent script, so the output has to be displayed in *unbuffered mode*. This is done with the `-u` flag.

Use `python -u script.py` instead of the conventional `python script.py`, as can be seen in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

Comment: To prevent your script's own windows being suppressed (not sure exactly what is going on here), run the call to Python as an argument to `cmd` by preprending `cmd /c`. For example, I'm using `cmd /c python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` so my Cocos2D window shows up.