# How to make NppExec show script-created windows?

Tags: command-line, python, notepad++, nppexec

I am trying to run a Python script with NppExec. It runs fine (the console is updated with whatever I print to stdout in the script) but the window the script creates (through PyQt) never shows up. If I execute the same script in a standard shell (cmd.exe), the window shows up just fine. Actually, the splash screen of the application I want to launch (vitables) shows up under NppExec but not the main window.

**Update**: Strangely, I noticed it works fine on some machines (but not on others). Both the machines where it works and those where it does not use the same OS (Windows 7 SP1), the same Notepad++ version (5.8.6) and NppExec version (0.4.1). I have tried updating to the latest versions (npp 6.5.3 and nppExec 0.5) but it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around in Eric's comment in the following question ([Stop NppExec from trapping console output until program finishes](https://superuser.com/questions/381942/stop-nppexec-from-trapping-console-output-until-program-finishes)), but is there a better way?

For reference, I had the additional problem that both the program to run and its argument need to be quoted (their path contain spaces), so I had to use an extra pair of quotes:

```
cmd /c ""c:\my path to python with spaces\python" -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""
```

**Update**: the same workaround is found in the following post:

http://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/672146/thread/4e2bc155/

In fact, that post is even copied verbatim in section 4.6.4. "Run Python scripts with wxPython" of NppExec manual. Sadly that manual is very poorly referenced by Google, hence my question here.